# Displaying widget according to click event does not work when the app is loaded for first time

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below where the widget of the right sidebar is supposed to be displayed only when the `"Plot"` tabpanel is active and this actually happens except of the 1st time the app is loaded when the widget is displayed in the `'Summary'` tabpanel as well. I understand that this is happening because the activation comes with the click on tabpanel name. But how can I fix it?

```
library(golem)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      golem::activate_js(),
      navbarPage("Navbar!",
                 tabPanel("Summary"

                 ),
                 tabPanel("Plot"
                 )), 
      tags$script(
        '$("a[data-toggle=\'tab\']").click(function(){
          Shiny.setInputValue("tabactive", $(this).data("value"))
        })'
      )
    ),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
      background = "dark",
      rightSidebarTabContent(
        id = 1,
        title = "Tab 1",
        icon = "desktop",
        active = TRUE,
        uiOutput("sl")

      )

    ),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$sl<-renderUI({
      sliderInput(
        "obs",
        "Number of observations:",
        min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
      )
    })

    observeEvent( input$tabactive , {
      if (input$tabactive == "Plot"){
        golem::invoke_js("showid", "sl")
      } else {
        golem::invoke_js("hideid", "sl")
      }
    })



  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the initial rendering via adding `req(input$tabactive)` to your `renderUI` call:

```
library(golem)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      golem::activate_js(),
      navbarPage("Navbar!",
                 tabPanel("Summary"

                 ),
                 tabPanel("Plot"
                 )), 
      tags$script(
        '$("a[data-toggle=\'tab\']").click(function(){
          Shiny.setInputValue("tabactive", $(this).data("value"))
        })'
      )
    ),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
      background = "dark",
      rightSidebarTabContent(
        id = 1,
        title = "Tab 1",
        icon = "desktop",
        active = TRUE,
        uiOutput("sl")

      )

    ),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$sl <- renderUI({
      req(input$tabactive)
      sliderInput(
        "obs",
        "Number of observations:",
        min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
      )
    })

    observeEvent( input$tabactive , {
      if (input$tabactive == "Plot"){
        golem::invoke_js("showid", "sl")
      } else {
        golem::invoke_js("hideid", "sl")
      }
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: mate could you take a look at this similar issue here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842442/connect-shiny-widget-display-with-specific-navbar-tabpanel-selection